# DNN MVC Module with Sql Hierarchy Id

Tags: petapoco, dotnetnuke, dnn9

Quick question here. Has anyone used the sql hierarchy id type in their dnn mvc module with peta poco? Do you need to write a custom query to cast the data type? Do you need to add sql server types to the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, PetaPoco doesn't support this type. However, PetaPoco does support some flexible mapping points.

Off the top of my head, you can declare your own mapping type. See [Interface](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/master/PetaPoco/Core/IMapper.cs) & [Docs](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Mapping-Pocos#roll-your-own-mapper) & [Registration](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Fluent-Configuration)

Another method is to hook the type mapping using the fluent configuration method. See [example](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/development/PetaPoco.Tests.Integration/Databases/Sqlite/SqliteDBTestProvider.cs) & [Docs](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/Fluent-Configuration)